# need help to resolve this error:Scons

Tags: scons

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: The Options class is deprecated; use the Variables class instead.
File "/home/poly/Downloads/ascend/ascend-0.9.5.116/SConstruct", line 12, in <module>

scons: warning: The BoolOption() function is deprecated; use the BoolVariable()    function instead.
File "/home/poly/Downloads/ascend/ascend-0.9.5.116/SConstruct", line 130, in <module>

scons: warning: The ListOption() function is deprecated; use the ListVariable() function instead.
File "/home/poly/Downloads/ascend/ascend-0.9.5.116/SConstruct", line 168, in <module>

scons: warning: The PackageOption() function is deprecated; use the PackageVariable() function instead.
File "/home/poly/Downloads/ascend/ascend-0.9.5.116/SConstruct", line 253, in <module>

scons: warning: The env.Copy() method is deprecated; use the env.Clone() method instead.
File "/home/poly/Downloads/ascend/ascend-0.9.5.116/scons/graphviz.py", line 43, in generate
Package libagraph was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libagraph.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libagraph' found
TCL= /usr
TCL_CPPPATH = $TCL/include
TCL_LIBPATH = $TCL/lib
TCL_LIB = tcl8.5
CC = gcc
CXX = g++
FORTRAN= gfortran
ABSOLUTE PATHS = True
INSTALL_ASCDATA = $INSTALL_SHARE/ascend
INSTALL_PREFIX = /usr/local
INSTALL_MODELS = $INSTALL_ASCDATA/models
INSTALL_SOLVERS = $INSTALL_ASCDATA/solvers
DEFAULT_ASCENDLIBRARY = $INSTALL_MODELS
DEFAULT_ASCENDSOLVERS = $INSTALL_SOLVERS
Scons version is not OK. Please try version 0.96.92 or 0.96.93,
or consult the developers in the case of newer versions. Modify
the function 'sconsversioncheck' in the file SConstruct if you
want to *force* SCons to continue.
```

I don't know what is happening. I am trying to install ascend but before that i needed scons. i installed scons using

```
yum install scons subversion tk-devel flex bison gcc-gfortran gcc-c++ python-devel sundials-devel graphviz-devel swig
```

Plaese help
i m installing ascend 0.9.8 on fedora 15 32-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the message says, the version of SCons in your package manager is too old.

SCons has relatively few dependencies, just install it from source. Install instructions [here](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c95.html), download [here](http://www.scons.org/download.php).